# Drupal 7 custom themes

Tags: drupal, themes

I really need help.

I have decided to build a website with drupal so that i can add drupal to my skills, but i am starting to think i have made a big mistake.

I am a wordpress developer and have built most off my websites with wordpress. The probalm i am have is custom templates with wordpress i can just create a custom temaplate by add some shortcode to the head off my theme file easy.

How do you do this with drupal is it completely modular can you adjust themes i am struggling trying to find a way off doing this. i started with drupal 6 and this was possible by doing the following.

```
page-node-17.tpl.php
```

i could just then assign this to the specific page with a node of 17, i have since switch to drupal 7 and this doesnt work.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is still completely possible, however, the naming convention changed.  Now you will need to name it: `page--node--17.tpl.php`.  For more information on naming templates, see [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).  Also, the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) is a very useful resource.